# How to save a label for an extra user meta field and to display it later?

Tags: user-meta

Bellow is how I currently add, save and display an extra user meta field:

```
/* Add Extra Fields to the User Profile */
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { 
  ?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
    <th><label for="publications"><?php _e("Publications"); ?></label></th>
    <td>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="450" name="publications" id="publications"  class="regular-text" />
    <?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'publications', $user->ID ) ); ?>
    </textarea><br />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  <?php 
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

/* Save extra user profile fields */
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'publications', $_POST['publications'] );
}

/* Display the selected user meta data with a shortcode */
add_shortcode('user_meta', 'user_meta_shortcode_handler');
/* usage: [user_meta user_id=1] */
function user_meta_shortcode_handler($atts,$content=null){ ?>
  <?php
    echo '<h3>Publicații</h3>';
    echo wpautop(get_user_meta($atts['user_id'], 'publications', true));
  ?>
  <?php
}
```

In this way, with only one shortcode I can display multiple metadata at the same time. Now I want to modify this code to be able to save also a label for each user meta field and to display it/them later together with the corresponding value. How to do this with my code?

Comment: I do not want to insert a label parameter in the shortcode, as suggested @birgire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use a label parameter in your shortcode, like this:

```
[user_meta user_id="1" label="publications"]
```

with these code changes:

```
* Display the selected user meta data with a shortcode */
add_shortcode('user_meta', 'user_meta_shortcode_handler');

/* usage: [user_meta user_id="1" label="publications"] */
function user_meta_shortcode_handler($atts,$content=null){ 
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
         'user_id' => '1',
         'label' => 'publications'
     ), $atts ) );          

    $output.='<h3>'.$label.'</h3>';
    $output.= wpautop(get_user_meta($user_id, 'publications', true));
    return $output;
}
```

**EDIT:**

ok, maybe you mean something like this:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

/* Add Extra Fields to the User Profile */
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { 
  ?>
    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="my_label"><?php _e("Publications Label"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'my_label', $user->ID ); ?>" name="my_label" id="my_label"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="my_publications"><?php _e("Publications"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="450" name="my_publications" id="my_publications"  class="regular-text" /><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'my_publications', $user->ID ); ?></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
  <?php 
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

/* Save extra user profile fields */
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_label', esc_attr($_POST['my_label']) );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'my_publications', esc_attr($_POST['my_publications']) );
}

/* Display the selected user meta data with a shortcode */
add_shortcode('user_meta', 'user_meta_shortcode_handler');
/* usage: [user_meta user_id="1"] */
function user_meta_shortcode_handler($atts,$content=null){ 
     extract( shortcode_atts( array(
         'user_id' => '1',
     ), $atts ) );          

    $output.='<h3>';
    $output.= wpautop(get_user_meta($user_id, 'my_label', true));
    $output.='</h3>';
    $output.= wpautop(get_user_meta($user_id, 'my_publications', true));
    return $output;
}
```

[image: extra user profile fields (publications textarea + label input)]

Comment: The idea is that with the initial shortcode I can display multiple metadata with (potentially) multiple labels at the same time (I mean with only one shortcode), but with yours not.

Comment: I updated the above code.

Comment: Thank you! The second version is very close to what I need! Now, I think, I can adapt/customize it myself. Thank you again!

Comment: ok great ;-) I also used a "return" instead of "echo" in the shortcode function, otherwise it will always display the shortcode content before the post content. Good luck with your project.